# Pandas with oddly shaped excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, pivot

I have some data from the excel file that looks like this

| First | Last | Unnamed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith |  |
| Susan | Johnson |  |
| House | Time | 15 (mins) |
| 250,000 | Zip | XXXXX |
| 150,000 |  |  |
| 75,000 |  |  |
| 800,000 |  |  |

I would like the data to look like this

| First | Last | House | Time | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | 250,000 | 15 (mins) | XXXXX |
| Susan | Johnson | 150,000 |  |  |
|  |  | 75,000 |  |  |
|  |  | 800,000 |  |  |

There is a lot of data that repeats itself how table one looks so this would have to repeat multiple times.

I have read through pandas' pivot documentation but I cannot figure out how to get my data how I want it using this way.

I have done this not using pivot and it works but then I get stuck on the House part:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Last'] == 'Time':
        currentZip = df.loc[index, 'Unnamed']
        df.loc[index, 'Unnamed'] = ''
        df.loc[index-2, 'Time'] = currentZip
```

You may assume I have created the Column 'Time' and 'Zip' as well.

Comment: you gotta do this on Excel, format the file first since you don't have a certain pattern to read this file, once the header is on top of the values, and once it is on the left of the variables. it is going to be quite tedious. a header line must contain only headers.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the answer.